# Python on OSX: force py.test to not use the system version of python

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I have 10.11 OSX, it has python installed as all the other OSX build, in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

Although when I run `which python` I get `/usr/local/bin/python`, which is a symlink to `../Cellar/python/2.7.13_2/bin/python`

So far so good; I did install python via Brew, to use virtualenv and it works fine following the instructions here: [www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/instal-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/)

Although I would like to not use virtualenv, since I am using py.test, but py.test is forced for some reason to use the system python, instead than going for the usr/local/bin/ symlink.

How do I force py.test to NOT use the system version of python? I did try to change PYTHONPATH adding the symlink location but it didn't work

Comment: Why do you not want to use virtualenv? This might be the simplest and cleanest approach. It can be a little awkward at first, but it gives you great flexibility...

Comment: virtualenv is an extra setup; the more elements you add in a process, the more are the chances that something could go wrong. Virtualenv is good for test a process, but I would not rely on it for day by day activities to be honest, and even less when running integrity tests.

Comment: IMO you'll likely find that using virtualenv is worth it in the long run, especially if you are writing more than one program on your computer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the path to the `bin` directory of the python version you want, and put it first in your PATH:

```
PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH
```

Edit your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile` or such to ensure that `python` dir path is first in your `PATH` before any other paths to `bin` dirs in there for other `python` versions.

Or else just remove those `bin` dirs for other `python` versions from your `PATH` altogether.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot! I assume I can use the same principle to totally phase out the existing Python version on my OSX system, and just use the one that I get from Brew. Planning to move eventually to 3.0, so it is good to know that I can change the path order and be able to dictate which version will be used.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working, and yeah with your environment set up to use the particular Python runtime you want, the other installed Python(s) will just be ignored.